# Инвертировать запрос

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть регулярное выражение вида

```
/([а-яA-Z0-9])/ig
```

Мне нужно его инвертировать так, что бы он искал все символы, кроме данных.

---

Вот так не работает:

```
/(?![а-яA-Z0-9])/ig
```

UPD: 
В конечном результате
Есть произвольная строка надо проверить, есть ли в строке **не буквы и не цифры**.

Comment: `^` внутри `[]` как отрицание работает

Comment: @Grundy, это проблему не решает.

Comment: Без примеров не совсем ясно, что требуется.

Comment: Есть произвольная строка. Надо проверить, есть ли в ней не буквы и не цифры.

Comment: `var result = /[^а-яёA-Z0-9]/i.test(s)`

Comment: Или `var result = !/^[а-яёA-Z0-9]$/i.test(s)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, а `\W` не подойдет тут?

Comment: @Grundy: Всё зависит от того, нужно ли учитывать `_`.

Comment: @Grundy Зависит от постановки задачи `искал все символы, кроме данных.` или `проверить, есть ли в строке не буквы и не цифры.`

Comment: @Иван Что-нибудь помогло? Вам нужна проверка всех букв любого алфавита? Или только рус./англ.?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function test() {
  var str = document.getElementById("text").value;
  var res = /[^а-яA-Z0-9]/i.test(str);
  if (res)
    console.log("Есть");
  else
    console.log("Нет");
}
```

```html
<input id="text" type="text" />
<button id="btn" onclick="test()">Test</button>
```